# Adafriut LED backpack

Tags: led, adafruit

Adafruit LED backpack
Am I being stupid (probably yes)
I'm after python 3 versions of this module, every time I download it I get the python 2.7 versions

getting my module from

```
git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_LED_Backpack.git
```

I'm doing this on a raspberry pi

the python 2 version works fine but my program is written in python 3

new error I'm getting is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_LED_Backpack/matrix8x16_test.py", line 37,
>   in 
>       display.begin()   File "/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_LED_Backpack/Adafruit_LED_Backpack/HT16K33.py",
>   line 53, in begin
>       self._device.writeList(HT16K33_SYSTEM_SETUP | HT16K33_OSCILLATOR, [])   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line
>   127, in writeList
>       self._bus.write_i2c_block_data(self._address, register, data)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py",
>   line 274, in write_i2c_block_data
>       self._device.write(data) OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

Comment: it looks as if this code is compatible with both python 2.7 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

this package seems to be compatible between both python 2 & 3.

after cloning the package, when you want to install it in python interpreter, execute this command:

```
sudo python -3 setup.py install
```

'-3' means running on python 3.

Comment: Hi thanks for that, however I've tried that and it still seems to be installing the python 2 version..................

Comment: is there some way an rpi is remembering my installs................., I'm getting annoyed, such a simple process..... when it works. I'm close to reinstalling the o/s

Comment: Try to import the package in python 3 terminal. If you manage to import it in py3 terminal, then it's properly installed. Do you have problems using the package in python 3 or is it just that you see in package files stuff mentioning py2. 7? It should be the same files for both python versions? By the way, using 3.5 or 3.6?

Comment: And if you can dump or make a screenshot when you encounter the problem, it may help.

Comment: hi, thanks for that, I now have python 3 programs to play with, however I get another error I don't understand, I've pasted it above

Comment: ignore that, I forgot to connect the chip...................... hence the input out put error..., sometimes you cant see the wood for the tress. thanks for the help